# JAX-RS implementantion in Glassfish 4

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, glassfish-4

I don't understand one thing with JavaEE and Glassfish.

As far as I know JavaEE is a set of interfaces of different services. One of them is JAX-RS which is used for creating RESTful applications.

But in order to use one of these interfaces I need an implementantion of it. So there are plenty of implementantions, for instance RESTEasy, Jersey etc. But I'm confused a bit. Which implementantion does Glassfish use? It has its own or implement one of existing, for example Jersey?

My question is not only about JAX-RS but also about other interfaces but I suppose that it's analogously for every interface.

Comment: Glashfish uses Jersey.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find every implementantion that Glassfish uses?

Comment: Generally a Google for "glassfish <apiname>" is the fastest. When discussing a particular JavaEE specification API, people like to iterate over which implementation comes with each of the popular JavaEE containers. I would also like to stress that caring about it is exactly what the JavaEE platform attempts to take away from you. You shouldn't have to care which implementation is used, until you run into misery at which point it will be very clear which implementation it is from the exception stacktrace.

Comment: @Gimby Probably you're right but I like to have deep understanding what I learn and I've just wanted to know that. :)

Comment: The understanding is in the API, not the implementation. Oracle and affiliates have made a gigantic effort to beat the JavaEE platform into something manageable and lightweight through standardization and with JavaEE7 they're closer than ever to something beautiful, now we as developers have to help them by appreciating their efforts and just rolling with it :)

Comment: Yeah, to understand JavaEE I need to understand API but I want to understand also how Glassfish works, what implementations of API exists and which of them Glassfish uses, which is better etc. I'm just curious. :)

Comment: @tdudzik This [link](https://glassfish.java.net/downloads/ri/) might be useful for you.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin probably this is exactly what I've been looking for, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, each application server has it's own implementation of different Java EE specifications, I'll give you few examples for Glassfish and JBoss (currently Wildfly)

- JAX-RS - Glassfish is using Jersey, which is also reference implementation (in opposed to JBoss or Wildfly which uses RESTEasy)
- JPA - Glassfish uses EclipseLink (again, reference implementation) and JBoss has Hibernate
- CDI - both has Weld
- JTA - Glassfish uses JTA Implementation For Glassfish, JBoss has Narayana
- JSF - both uses Mojarra

What it means for you as a developer that your project typically needs to depend only on interface described in specification (unless you want something special outside of the spec), so you don't care about implementation and just let your application server inject correct one. This is good for your project because you don't need that many dependencies. You can also specify those dependencies as `provided` via Maven so when you build your project it won't contain additional JARs and it will give you more lightweight JAR or WAR.